# How to test Django Form ChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I've been stuck trying to test a Form `ChoiceField` in Django.

I have a `Form` with a single `ChoiceField`:

```
class PickPlanForm(forms.Form):
    "Set the `plan` session cookie for choice here."

    plan_choices = Plan.objects.get_choices()

    # Field
    plan = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=plan_choices)
```

This is the tuple list of my `plan_choices`:

```
[('Bronze', 'Bronze ($10.00 per month)'),
 ('Silver', 'Silver ($20.00 per month)')]
```

I am trying to test it in the following way:

```
response = self.client.post(reverse('payment:register_step3'),
    {'plan': 'Bronze'}, follow=True)
self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('payment:register_step4'))
```

However, when running my tests, I keep getting the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/djcode/textress_concierge/textress/main/tests/test_views.py", line 170, in test_register_step3
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('payment:register_step4'))
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/textress/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 263, in assertRedirects
    (response.status_code, status_code))
AssertionError: False is not True : Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)
```

I am using:

```
Django 1.6.8
Python 3.4
```

I'm thinking this is something easy that I am missing?

thank you

**Edit: add View**

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin

class PickPlanView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    """
    Step #3 of Registration

    Pick a Plan, and save the Plan as a `session cookie` before creating
    the Stipe Customer/Subscription using the Plan Choice.
    """
    template_name = 'main/hotel_form.html'
    form_class = PickPlanForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('payment:register_step4')
    authenticated_redirect_url = settings.VERIFY_LOGOUT_URL

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """Add the `request` Obj to Form, so I can set the PlanPick as a
            session cookie for the time being."""
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs
```

**Notes on View:**

It just accepts the Form Choice.

It works when I test it manually.

I am just having trouble with the `Django ChoiceField Test` part because I haven't tested a `ChoiceField` before.

Thank you

Comment: Without seeing your view, it's really hard to tell why your test is failing.

Comment: Where/how exactly do you redirect to ``payment:register_step4``? Does the redirect occur from within the POST handler of ``payment:register_step3``?

Comment: @Brandon I have added my View.  Thank you for your help. Please let me know.  Basically it works when testing manually, which is what leads me to think that it is a ChoiceField Test syntax error, or the wrong `{'choice': 'value'}` combination. Thanks

Comment: @sthzg yes, I have added my view.  It is a CBV `FormView`, so it is handled by the `success_url`

Comment: Do you login the test client in your unit test?

Comment: @sthzg yes I do `self.client.login(...)` earlier in the test.  So, is my syntax correct for picking a Form Choice as `{'plan': 'Bronze'}` correct?  If so, I will try to trouble shoot a different way. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, I could bring the test to fail in exactly the same way, if I post an invalid choice. Posting 'Bronze' passes the test, but I have the choices hardcoded and don't fetch them dynamically. Makes me think... do the plans exist in the database of the unit test and are they fetched correctly from ``Plan.objects.get_choices()``?

Comment: @sthzg you are correct. It is a database related issue.  If you post your last comment as the Answer, I am going to accept it. Thank you for your help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could bring the test to fail in exactly the same way, if I post an invalid choice. Posting *Bronze* passes the test, but I have the choices hardcoded in the `form` class and don't fetch them dynamically from the database.

Makes me think if the plans exist in the database of the unit test (or in a mocked `queryset`) so that they are fetched correctly from `Plan.objects.get_choices()`?